# Difference between and / or clause in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am new to mongo db and trying to understand how to query a db.
I was reading a tutorial from this link http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-mongodb-part-1--net-22879

Following this tutorial I created a simple db like below,

```
db.nettuts.insert({
first: 'matthew',
last: 'setter',
dob: '21/04/1978',
gender: 'm',
hair_colour: 'brown',
occupation: 'developer',
nationality: 'australian'
});
    db.nettuts.insert({
first: 'james',
last: 'caan',
dob: '26/03/1940',
gender: 'm',
hair_colour: 'brown',
occupation: 'actor',
nationality: 'american'
});
db.nettuts.insert({
first: 'arnold',
last: 'schwarzenegger',
dob: '03/06/1925',
gender: 'm',
hair_colour: 'brown',
occupation: 'actor',
nationality: 'american'
});
db.nettuts.insert({
first: 'tony',
last: 'curtis',
dob: '21/04/1978',
gender: 'm',
hair_colour: 'brown',
occupation: 'developer',
nationality: 'american'
});
db.nettuts.insert({
first: 'jamie lee',
last: 'curtis',
dob: '22/11/1958',
gender: 'f',
hair_colour: 'brown',
occupation: 'actor',
nationality: 'american'
});
db.nettuts.insert({
first: 'michael',
last: 'caine',
dob: '14/03/1933',
gender: 'm',
hair_colour: 'brown',
occupation: 'actor',
nationality: 'english'
});
db.nettuts.insert({
first: 'judi',
last: 'dench',
dob: '09/12/1934',
gender: 'f',
hair_colour: 'white',
occupation: 'actress',
nationality: 'english'
});
```

and was trying to use querys like this below

```
db.nettuts.find({gender: 'm'});
```

which returned all the actors who are male.

When I tried the command

```
db.nettuts.find({gender: 'm', $or: [{nationality: 'english'}]});
```

it returned.

```
> db.nettuts.find({gender: "m", $or: [{nationality: "english"}]});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53064b7979d90b140e53df3e"), "first" : "michael", "last" : "caine",      "dob" : "14/03/1933", "gender" : "m", "hair_colour" : "brown", "occupation" : "actor", "nationality" : "english" }
>
```

When I tried the same command, this time with "and" clause

```
db.nettuts.find({gender: 'm', $and: [{nationality: 'english'}]});
```

I got the same output as when I used $or

```
> db.nettuts.find({gender: "m", $and: [{nationality: "english"}]});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53064b7979d90b140e53df3e"), "first" : "michael", "last" : "caine", "dob" : "14/03/1933", "gender" : "m", "hair_colour" : "brown", "occupation" : "actor", "nationality" : "english" }
>
```

So given these two output what is the difference between "or" clause and "and" clause here. Please help me understand.

Comment: Try putting more conditions to $or/$and arrays. You'll see the difference

Comment: `db.nettuts.find({$or:[{nationality: "english"},{gender: "m"}]});` would be the correct way to use `or` and `db.nettuts.find({$and:[{nationality: "english"},{gender: "m"}]});` would be the correct way to use `and`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `$or` or `$and` with an array with only one entry is quite pointless, because both operators apply to the array which is assigned to them. They don't apply to any other parts of the match-object.

When you want to find all actors which are male *or* english, you would do this:

```
db.nettus.find({
     $or: [
          { "gender": "m"},
          { "nationality": "english"}
     ]   
});
```

To find all actors which are male *and* english, you don't even need the $and-operator:

```
db.nettus.find({
     "gender": "m",
     "nationality": "english"
});
```

There are quite few situations where you really *must* use the $and-operator. The only situation where you have no alternative is when you need to apply **the same operator** to **the same field** multiple times. In this example we select all people whose age [can be divided](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/mod/#op._S_mod) by 3 and 5.

```
db.people.find({
     $and: [
          { age: $mod [ 3, 0] },
          { age: $mod [ 5, 0] }
     ]
});
```

Comment: This is a better example of what I was trying to say in my answer. Here's the source for more examples: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/